# Dotnet :- How to achieve windows authentication in window form application?

Tags: .net, desktop-application

I want to make a windows form application and want to use windows authentication to log in the user, it has to be used in intranet. the applcation should accept the user name and password from user and should authenticate it. how to achieve this.

Comment: Here is one [implementation](http://geekswithblogs.net/Ramaraju/archive/2009/07/14/windows_authentication_in_winform_application.aspx)

Comment: @ Sanjeev :- i used ur idea. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using Interop Services.  Use the below Code.

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(string userName, string domainName, string password, int LogonType, int LogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    public bool IsValidateCredentials(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        IntPtr tokenHandler = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool isValid = LogonUser(userName, domain, password, 3, 0, ref tokenHandler);
        return isValid;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.UserName` gives you the username of the current user. A password is not needed since the user have logged into windows.

Alternative: [WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Principal_WindowsIdentity_GetCurrent)

Comment: Environment.Username gives me the logged in username but is it enough to allow login to my application? I will naturally need to match the logged in user with a user in my users table and doing this by just username looks weak. What if the someone creates a local domain on his computer with the same name of the intranet domain and creates a user with the name of the one he wants to crack. So he can login with any user hew wants. Am I wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution? We have windows authentication in our desktop app but we do not validate the domain that means anyone can login with the local domain and a matching user name.

Comment: You can use `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`, there you have the domain name

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link to apply windows Authentication in Intranet:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb882216.aspx