# Enable Single Sign-On using C#

Tags: c#, single-sign-on

I am doing a C# application that on sign-in, will enable Single Sign-On(SSO) on Windows 7 terminals. I have tried things found on this site which constisted of making a GPO, but I am unable do install the, gpmgmt 1.0 Type Library needed to make a GPO code, saying it is incompatible with my Windows.

Anybody has a suggestion of how I can make this work using whatever method. 
I have done a lot of research and previous topics on this site did not work...

This is the code I tried... But unable to get the right library to make it work, and I am not even sure it is fine...

```
GPMGMTLib.GPM gpm = new GPMGMTLib.GPM();  
GPMGMTLib.GPMConstants gpc = gpm.GetConstants();  
GPMGMTLib.GPMDomain gpd =  gpm.GetDomain(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN"), "", gpc.UseAnyDC);  
GPMGMTLib.GPMSearchCriteria gps = gpm.CreateSearchCriteria();  

GPMGMTLib.IGPMGPOCollection gpoc = gpd.SearchGPOs(gps);  

string outputString = "";  
foreach (GPMGMTLib.GPMGPO name in gpoc)
{  
    outputString += "ID: " + name.ID + "\tName: " + name.DisplayName + "\r\n";  
}  
MessageBox.Show(outputString);
```

gpoadmin.dll says it is incompatible

Comment: Why can't you use Windows Authentication? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321671/dotnet-how-to-achieve-windows-authentication-in-window-form-application

Comment: because the client uses single sign-on... and adding this functionality to the app I am making would be nice I think.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading it sounds like you just want to identify the currently logged in user.  You can do that with `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`.  Alternatively you can get the logged in user name via the `Environment.UserName` property.

**WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent Method**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0.aspx

**Environment.UserName Property**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx