# authorization username and password from sql server in windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have a widows application that download file from folder in server, this folder has windows authentication mode for security (for "?" user);my win application have username and password for access this folder, now I need solution for check username and password when download file if this username and password is in my SQL Server database win application can download file else can't download file.

My question: how can I check the username and password in windows authentication mode in C#?

I'm sorry for bad language

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321671/dotnet-how-to-achieve-windows-authentication-in-window-form-application), may be that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Window Authentication Functionality to a C# Desktop Application

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Add-Window-Authentication-833ba913